# Separability in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field. Then any $f \in F[x]$ is separable.

How do you tackle this?

I thought of letting $f \in F[x]$ be irreducible, and let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$. Towards a contradiction, assume that $\alpha$ is a repeated root. Then $\alpha$ is also a root of the formal derivative of $f$ ; $D(f)$.

Since $f$ is irreducible, it must be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. But $\alpha$ is a root of $D(f)$ which has degree less than $f$. I think this is a contradiction, but I’m not sure?

Comment: A polynomial is separable iff it is coprime to its formal derivative. If your field has characteristic $p$ and $f(X) = Q(X^p)$ then $p \mid f^\prime$ so $f^\prime = 0$ in this field.. so $(f, f^\prime) = f$, and $f$ is inseparable.

Comment: Let $F = \mathbb{F}_p(t^p),K = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ then $K/F$ is not separable because $f(X) = X^p-t^p = (X-t)^p\in F[x]$ is irreducible. $f'(X)= p X^{p-1}  =0 \in F[X]$. $t$ is a root of $f$ as well as of $f'$. If $f' \ne 0$ then yes it would contradict $f$ is the minimal polynomial. With $F = \mathbb{F}_p$  : $f$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $f$ not separable. Thus $f' = 0$  so $f(X) = g(X^p) = g(X)^p$. And $g(\alpha)^p = 0$ implies $g(\alpha) = 0$ (why ?) contradicting the minimality of $f$.

Comment: @reuns Ok, thank you. So is my proof incorrect or did I just need to explain the contradiction for it to be correct?

Comment: @theman the statement isn't true.. you're saying any $f \in F[X]$ with $F$ a finite field is separable?

Comment: @ theman What do you not understand in what we said ? $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is a double root implies $f' = 0$, because this is the only way for $f'(\alpha) = 0$ not to contradict the minimality of $f$. I proposed a way to finish the proof from there.

Comment: @reuns So from the fact that $f’ = 0$, I get that $f$ must then be a polynomial in $x^p$. I don’t know why this shows that $f$ is then separable?

Comment: $f' = 0$ implies $f(X) = g(X^p) $. Then $ g(X^p) = g(X)^p$ (this is true for $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$, if $f \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}[X]$ then $g(X^p)= g^{\phi^{-1}}(X)^p$ where $\phi$ is the Frobenius, applied to the coefficients of $g$)

Comment: Well, even $(f(x))^2$ is not separable. The right question is whether every *irreducible* $\Bbb F_p$-polynomial is separable.

Comment: @Lubin So it is true for irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.